# Questions about Riemann rearrangement theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was reading about Riemann rearrangement theorem on [Wikipedia][1] ,but I have several question, it says:

> The map $σ$  is injective,and $1$ belongs to the range of $σ$,  either as image of $1$ (if $a_1 > 0$), or as image of $m _1 + 1$ (if $a_1 < 0$). to exceed $M$, starting with $n = p + 1$, and then adding just enough negative terms to be less than $M$, starting with $n = q + 1$. Extend $σ$ in an injective manner, in order to cover all terms selected so far, and observe that $a_2$ must have been selected now or before, thus $2$ belongs to the range of this extension. The process will have infinitely many such "changes of direction". One eventually obtains a rearrangement  $∑ a_{σ (n)}$.

**1)** Why $1$ can't be the image of another indexes except $1$ or $m_1+1$?

**2)** Also why if $a_{1}>0$ then $1$ is the image of itself and if $a_{1}<0$ then $1$ is the image of $m_1+1$?

> **Existence of a rearrangement that diverges to infinity**
>
> Let $\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }a_{i}$ be a conditionally convergent series. The following is a proof that there exists a rearrangement of this series that tends to $\infty$  (a similar argument can be used to show that  $-\infty $  can also be attained).
>
> Let ${\displaystyle p_{1}<p_{2}<p_{3}<\cdots }$ be the sequence of indexes such that each ${\displaystyle a_{p_{i}}}$ is positive, and define ${\displaystyle n_{1}<n_{2}<n_{3}<\cdots }$ to be the indexes such that each ${\displaystyle a_{n_{i}}} $is negative (again assuming that ${\displaystyle a_{i}}a_{i}$ is never $0$). Each natural number will appear in exactly one of the sequences ${\displaystyle (p_{i})}$ and ${\displaystyle (n_{i}).}$
>
> Let $b_{1}$ be the smallest natural number such that
>
> $${\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{b_{1}}a_{p_{i}}\geq |a_{n_{1}}|+1.}$$
>
> Such a value must exist since ${\displaystyle (a_{p_{i}}),}$ the subsequence of positive terms of ${\displaystyle (a_{i}),}$ diverges. Similarly, let ${\displaystyle b_{2}}$ be the smallest natural number such that:
>
> $${\displaystyle \sum _{i=b_{1}+1}^{b_{2}}a_{p_{i}}\geq |a_{n_{2}}|+1,}{\displaystyle}$$
>   and so on.

**3)** I don't understand the last line,how the existence of such value is followed by the divergence of $\left(a_{p_{i}}\right)$?

Comment: Would you like *not* to use images? It will make reading the question much easier (and searching)

Answer (score 1):

1/2) One wants to add up the first $m_1$ positive terms. If $a_1$ is positive, then $m_1=0.$ if not, $m_1>0.$ All natural numbers are either $1$ or $m_1+1$ for some positive integer $m_1.$

3) because now your sum is greater than or equal to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (|a_n|+1).$ An infinite series only converges if the terms go to zero. These terms go to 1, since $|a_n|\to 0.$